# PHP: What gives faster execution time, include_once or if statement?

Tags: php, performance

I'm creating a theme for my client and they are really picky on the page load time.

So I've thought that the less code will help the page load faster, and I come across the php code to include once.

```
<?php
include_once "a.php"; // this will include a.php
?>
```

and if I do with the if statement to include once I have to declare a variable and change the variable to false after the second check

What will be the most efficient coding and help page performance?

I also want to know if there is even better way of coding to help to make the page load faster when we want to execute the code from a file.

Thanks

Comment: As always, the only answer to "_is a or b faster?_" is to benchmark it yourself, but since PHP keeps track of files included, it is likely to be faster to `include_once()`.

Comment: No, not just that answer I also want to know if there is even better way of coding to help to make the page load faster when we want to execute the code from a file.

Comment: If there's a performance bottleneck, it's almost definitely not going to have anything to do with the speed of include_once. It will be with your database, or with the configuration of the server (caching, etc.) or with the number and size of resources requested from a particular page, or silly things like loading content synchronously from another server to your server before serving the page (saw that one being done last week).

Comment: The performance difference is minute, and any choice based on some perceived performance benefit would be a [tag:micro-optimization]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might have been true in the dim and distant past that include_once was a lot slower than include, but that was the dim and distant past.  PHP's include_once functionality has been optimized heavily since then.  Unfortunately, there's still lots of old articles floating around on the internet that make the claim that include_once is slow, even though it's no longer true.

Even if include_once was a lot slower than include, the odds are it wouldn't cause an appreciable performance impact unless you were including thousands and thousands of files.  Investing time on speeding it up is a [micro-optimization](/questions/tagged/micro-optimization), especially if you have no evidence that it's a bottleneck in your code.

**First and foremost in any project is getting the code to work to specifications**.  Code that's slow but works is still better than code that's fast but doesn't work.  Once you've got the code working and passing all its unit tests (you are using unit tests, right?) then you can start worrying about performance.  And when you get to that point the first thing you should do is profile your code to discover where the actual bottlenecks are, not start guessing at where you think they might be.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion PHP doesn't affect the file executing time very much. Unless you are looping trough 1000 loops or results I think you can't really speed up the file executing time. So I suggest you to don't worry about these things.

I should use the `include_once`/`require_once` because it is a PHP build-in function, simple to use and exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what is suggested [here](http://blog.seeit.org/2010/06/php-the-include-include_once-performance-debate/) and [there](http://arin.me/blog/php-require-vs-include-vs-require_once-vs-include_once-performance-test). require_once is the fastest. There is also `__autoload`, but with some performance draw backs. As it is suggested [here](http://blog.seeit.org/2010/06/php-the-include-include_once-performance-debate/) it matters if you use relative or absolute addressing too.

Comment: Autoload can only be used with OOP and I prefer [`spl_autoload_register`](http://php.net/spl-autoload-register) over `__autoload`

Comment: The performance drawbacks of autoloaders are somewhat "contentious" (not really the word I'm looking for...) - they inherently have an overhead, yes ... **but** they do allow you to load in the required files only as and when they're... erm ... required. :) So they can improve performance if you're pulling in a lot of libraries.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do even a very basic benchmark, like running it 1M times and then calculate the average:

```
<?php
echo microtime(true)."\n";
for ($i=0; $i<1000000; $i++) {
    include_once (__DIR__ .'/file.php');
}
echo microtime(true)."\n";
```